# Оптимизация sql запроса: Как получить следующую запись от текущей

Tags: sql-server, оптимизация

Есть следующая таблица

```
CREATE equipmentWork (
  id INT IDENTITY,
  equipment INT NOT NULL,
  start DATETIME NULL,
  stop DATETIME NULL,
  inWork BIGINT NULL,
  program VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_equipmentWork PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

мне необходимо получить данные за период, по определенному оборудованию, так же мне необходимо получить простой оборудования(*разность между временем завершения текущей программы и началом следующей*)

у меня получился следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
   w.program
   , w.start
   , w.stop
   , (SELECT
        TOP 1 w1.start
      FROM equipmentWork w1
      WHERE (w1.start >= @start AND w1.[stop] <= @stop)
        AND w1.equipment = @equipment AND w1.start>w.stop) AS NextStart
FROM equipmentWork w
WHERE w.equipment = @equipment
AND w.start >= @start
AND w.[stop] <= @stop
```

Запрос выполняется и результат соответствует ожиданиям но, скорость выполнения оставляет желать лучшего(в среднем составляет *1 минуту*).

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли *ускорить* выполнение данного запроса, что для этого необходимо сделать?

P.S.: версия `sql` сервера: 2008 R2

upd.:

```
SELECT
   w.program
   , w.start
   , w.stop
   , (SELECT
        TOP 1 w1.start
      FROM equipmentWork w1
      WHERE (w1.start >= @start AND w1.[stop] <= @stop)
        AND w1.equipment = @equipment AND w1.start>w.stop
      ORDER BY w1.start, w1.stop) AS NextStart
FROM equipmentWork w
WHERE w.equipment = @equipment
AND w.start >= @start
AND w.[stop] <= @stop
ORDER BY w.start, w.stop
```

Comment: Для начала, ваш запрос содержит несколько ошибок. Во-первых, `w1.equipment = 261` - явно не корректное сравнение. Во-вторых, во вложенном запросе не хватает order by - без сортировки операция top может работать лишь по счастливой случайности.

Comment: @PavelMayorov поправил условие *w1.equipment = @equipment*, добавил сортировку, скорость выполнения увеличилась в несколько раз: *8 секунд*, это можно сказать приемлемо. может есть еще какие либо мои *косяки*?

Comment: Бу-га-га. Даже не думал, что это ускорит :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov существенно ускорило, с 1 минуты до 8 секунд :)

Comment: @Bald А зачем у вас в подзапросе `w1.[stop] <= @stop` вы для последней строки выборки не хотите получать простой ? ну и проверка start>@start там то же не нужна т.к. есть проверка на start>w.stop. Если все верно и следующая запись не интересна - то посмотрите нет ли еще в вашей версии MS SQL функции `lag()`. А вообще план выполнения надо посмотреть

Comment: @Mike `lag` появился начиная с 2012 версии. убрал из *вложенного подзапроса* условия фильтрации по дате, время выполнения сократилось до *6 секунд*. мне необходимо получить простой только в заданном промежутке, т.е. в результат не должны попасть данные где `w.stop>@stop`

Comment: @Bald Тогда у вас задача гораздо интереснее, если нам дан промежуток до 16:00, а оборудование закончило работать в 15:00, и опять начало уже после промежутка я бы посчитал что простой на этом промежутке 1 час ... А план выполнения это то с чего вообще любая оптимизация начинается. Может у вас индекса по (equipment, start) нету или он по какой то причине не используется ...

Comment: @Mike описанная Вами ситуация может быть решена заданием большего временного интервала(или как более лучший вариант *размножать* при выполнении более суток ). по поводу индексов, на исходной таблице их нет(только: *primary key*)

Comment: @Bald Если данных много (а их прилично, ибо в чем он колупается 6-60 сек) то и основной запрос и подзапрос (ради каждой строки) делает полное сканирование таблицы ... Так сделайте ка вы индекс, что то мне подсказывает, что у вас много запросов с конкретным оборудованием и временем ...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41383/discussion-between-bald-and-mike).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае необходимо использовать оконные функции. Если бы это был SQL Server 2012, то можно было просто использовать функцию lag. Но т.к. это 2008, то придётся использовать row_number примерно так:

```
with 
w as (
    SELECT
        id
       , program
       , start
       , [stop]
       , row_number() over(partition by equipment order by start, [stop]) as rn
    FROM equipmentWork
    WHERE equipment = @equipment
    AND start >= @start
    AND [stop] <= @stop 
)

SELECT
   w.program
   , w.start
   , w.stop
   , w_next.start AS NextStart
FROM w
left join w w_next on w.equipment = w_next.equipment and w.rn = w_next.rn+1
ORDER BY w.start, w.stop
```

Т.е. мы делаем представление, добавляя порядковый номер для каждого equipment в соответствии с сортировкой, а затем соединяем представление само с собой по equipment и порядковому номеру равному необходимому нам порядковому номеру (в данном случае +1).

Это должно работать значительно быстрее вашего варианта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, запомню как один из способов. Ваш способ позволил сократить время выполнения запроса до *3 секунд*

Comment: Блок WHERE во внешнем запросе лишний, как и сравнение `equipment` в операторе `join` - туда попадают уже отобранные записи. Или же можно, напротив, убрать фильтры из внутреннего запроса.

Comment: ORDER BY, к слову, тут тоже лишний, хотя и может оказаться подсказкой оптимизатору.

Comment: @Bald проверьте варианты ^^

Comment: @PavelMayorov когда проверял данный пример я убирал лишнее условие во внешнем запросе, так как имеем уже отсортированный и отфильтрованный набор данных

Comment: @PavelMayorov внешнее условие действительно излишние, не доглядел, поправлю. ORDER BY всё-таки нужен, т.к. в представлении нет сортировки данных (order by в row_number не сортирует данные). Условие в join по equipment излишнее, но я бы его оставил, т.к. так очевиднее, а затрат на это не будет.

Comment: @АлексейШмелёв ну и что, что сортировки в представлении нет? Автор где-то упоминал что ему нужны упорядоченные данные?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov последний селект в вопросе автора с сортировкой.

Comment: @АлексейШмелёв это у него ответ на мой комментарий. В исходной задаче такого не требовалось.

Comment: @PavelMayorov В любом случае детерминированный результат всегда лучше. Вот, например, по-обновляйте эту страничку сейчас - то мой ответ на верху, то ваш. Потому что здесь сортировка не детерминирована, а заканчивается рейтингом ответа (который сейчас 3), а надо было ещё, например, по дате сортировать или т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы оптимизатор сумел оптимизировать запрос, надо написать его корректно:

1. Если в двух частях запроса содержатся одинаковые именованные параметры - это должен быть один и тот же параметр, а не два разных или параметр и константа. Если оптимизатор будет уверен что два параметра всегда равны - он сможет подобрать лучшую оптимизацию.
2. Любое использование конструкций, которым важен порядок записей (например, TOP) - должно сопровождаться указанием этого самого порядка. То есть конструкцией ORDER BY. Без этого TOP просто не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Нормально на SQL такой запрос не пишется - потому что у SQL нет базовых средств работы с последовательностями, он работает только с множествами.

И если результаты запроса обрабатываются на каком-либо языке программирования - лучше там и сделать постобработку. Если же требуется чистый T-SQL - то лучше всего будет завести хранимую процедуру, которая и сделает что требуется.

Документация для ознакомления: [Курсоры (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181441(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавить составной индекс в исходную таблицу по следующим полям: `Equipment`, `Start`

   `CREATE INDEX es
   ON CNCLog.dbo.equipmentWork (equipment, start)
   ON [PRIMARY]
   GO`
2. Сортировку сделать по полям *индекса* `es`: `ORDER BY equipment, start`;
3. Из подзапроса убрать условие `w.start >= @start AND w.[stop] <= @stop`;

---

Перенесено [отсюда](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41383/discussion-between-bald-and-mike)